# How to glue the text of multiple divs together?

Tags: css

I'm having some nested divs and I'd like to 'glue together' the text of the divs such that it seems to be a single sentence. This is my code (http://jsfiddle.net/gorwmgj1/):

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="field-name-field-plaats">
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even">This is some random text.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-name-field-aantal">
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even">10</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.content {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
}
.field-name-field-plaats::before {
    content:"@ ";
}
.field-name-field-plaats {
    display: inline;
}
.field-name-field-aantal::before {
    content:" (";
}
.field-name-field-aantal::after {
    content:"x)";
}
.field-name-field-aantal {
    display: inline;
}
.field-items {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

So, for example, the output should be something like

> @ This is
>
> some random
>
> text. (10x)

instead of

> @
>
> This is some
>
> random text.
>
> (10x)

How can I change my CSS to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple add this:

```
div{
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not too sure html is wise structured, but just turn your div into inline boxe :

```
.field-name-field-plaats div {
    display:inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gorwmgj1/1/